# Is there a way to netboot to a live version of Windows 7? (NOT net-install)

Tags: windows, netboot

I am working on a project and I would like to be able to netboot into a simple image of Windows 7, similar to how one can netboot into a live version of a Linux distribution. I don't need the ability to install Windows 7, just the ability to boot into Windows and have some basic functionality (command prompt, file explorer, etc.). What would be the best way (if any) to do this? What would I need?

I have looked into a program called [SERVA](http://www.vercot.com/~serva/), which provides some PXE booting support, and I've actually got it working for a few diagnostic tools (MemTest, SeaTools) as well as installation images for Windows 7 and 8. Would I be able to use SERVA for what I need?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can go with this.

Officially, Microsoft offers [Windows PE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825110.aspx) which has *very* basic functionality.  Typically it's used to deploy another OS or to repair an existing OS.

Unofficially, there are many third-party projects which try to add functionality to Windows PE to produce a live Linux type of experience.  I believe they're all based off [WinBuilder](http://winbuilder.net/), and others have been mentioned here in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own [Live Windows](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/winbuilder-win7pe-se-tutorial) with [Win7PE SE](http://w7pese.cwcodes.net/)

[image]

This adds Windows Explorer to WinPE and some basic tools.

Answer (score 0):

Serva can net install Windows/Linux images, net boot Linux Live distros and also (the Supporter version) can net boot any available Windows PE.
Remember there are license issues with the use of Windows PE plus it is time limited.

You can build customized Windows PE with Microsoft tools or some automated 3rd party tools like Winbuilder.

there is a product called ccboot that claims to boot windows 7 on a diskless client but I have no experience with it.